# Change Django ModelChoiceField to show users' full names rather than usernames

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I have a form in my Django app (not in admin) that allows staff members to select a user from a dropdown.

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=False), required = False)
```

The problem is that the dropdown shows users by usernames whereas I'd rather it show their full name from user.get_full_name() and use username only if that is not available. I only really need this change on this page, in other places like admin, I don't care if it uses username.

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can setup a custom `ModelChoiceField` that will return whatever label you'd like.

Place something like this within a fields.py or wherever applicable.

```
class UserModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return obj.get_full_name()
```

Then when creating your form, simply use that field

```
 UserModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=False), required = False)
```

More info can be found [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/)

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but it isn't forms.UserModelChoiceField it's wherever_you_put_that_class.UserModelChoiceField

Comment: This didn't work for me, I get the error `NameError: name 'UserModelChoiceField' is not defined`. I put it right after defining the class `UserModelChoiceField`. Do I have to do something else, like register the class or something? (And I am trying to do this in the Admin.)

Comment: Thank you for this solution, In 2022, I wish you a very happy new year.

Answer (score 36):

When working with a ModelForm, I found the following most useful so that I didn't have to redefine my queryset - in particular because I used limit_choices_to in the model definition:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "%s" % obj.get_full_name()
```

customised from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7805824/432992

Comment: Works like a charm !

Comment: Maybe error: 'ModelForm has no model class specified'. Need `class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm)` replace to `class MyModelForm(forms.Form)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the field with a custom `ModelChoiceField` and change the `label_from_instance` function to return `get_full_name` instead.  See the docs for `ModelChoiceField`: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change choices of the field in model form, try this adaptation of the Bartek's answer:

model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

form field:

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_full_name()
```

form:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['user']
        field_classes = {
            'user': UserModelChoiceField
        }
```

This approach will preserve params of the field (you don't need to specify `queryset`, `required` and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You can also make one custom ModelChoiceField to which you can pass a function. That way if you have different fields for which you want different attributes to be displayed, you can have only 1 class:

```
class CustomModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
name_function = staticmethod(lambda obj: obj)

def __init__(self, name_function, *args, **kwargs):
    if not name_function is None: self.name_function = name_function
    super(CustomModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def label_from_instance(self, obj):
     return self.name_function(obj);
```

You can then call it as simply as this:

```
form_field = CustomModelChoiceField(
    lambda obj: obj.get_full_name(),
    queryset=Whatever.objects.all(),
)
```

You can also pass None in case you're doing some dynamic stuff and it'll just basically default to a regular ModelChoiceField. I'm not too much of a python guy  but this works for me.