# How can I remove the key from this ModelForm

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have the following ModelForm and I'm getting the results I want, but I can't figure out how to remove the key from the results.

Form:

```
class TicketActionsForm(ModelForm):
assign = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Users.objects.values('user').filter(account=3), empty_label="  Select Admin  ")
```

View return statement:

```
return render_to_response('tickets/view.html',
    {'ticket':ticket,'ticketactions':TicketActionsForm()},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

Template:

```
{{ ticketactions.assign }}
```

Results:  (screenshot: http://snapplr.com/z7t7 )

```
<option value="" selected="selected">  Select Admin  </option> 
<option value="{&#39;user&#39;: u&#39;Chris&#39;}">{&#39;user&#39;: u&#39;Chris&#39;}    </option> 
<option value="{&#39;user&#39;: u&#39;mmiller&#39;}">{&#39;user&#39;: u&#39;mmiller&#39;}</option> 
<option value="{&#39;user&#39;: u&#39;millerm&#39;}">{&#39;user&#39;: u&#39;millerm&#39;}</option> 
<option value="{&#39;user&#39;: u&#39;Cindy222&#39;}">{&#39;user&#39;: u&#39;Cindy222&#39;}</option>
```

Edit:

I am able to update the label easily with the following over-ride, but I'm still stumbled on how to change the option values.  I can probably edit the data after it is POST'd, but I'd rather clean it up prior to that.

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
def label_from_instance(self, obj):
    return obj['user']
```

Resolution:

I ended up doing a little hack in the **init** to get the results I wanted.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TicketActionsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    newChoices = []
    for item in self.fields['assign'].queryset:
        choice=(item['user'],item['user'])
        newChoices.append(choice)
    self.fields['assign'].choices = newChoices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167824/change-django-modelchoicefield-to-show-users-full-names-rather-than-usernames/3167840#3167840) has a simple way of changing the labels used in a ModelChoiceField.

When you use a ModelChoiceField, you probably want to call `Users.objects.all()` rather than `Users.objects.values('user')`.

What you want to do then, would be to have the following code:

```
class UserModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_full_name()
```

and when you make your form, you should have the following code:

```
class TicketActionsForm(ModelForm):
    assign = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Users.objects.all().filter(account=3), empty_label="  Select Admin  ")
```

This way a set (more accurately, a `QuerySet`) of rows is passed to the ModelChoiceField object and it will have access to all the fields. Using the code above, you can control the label and when you change `objects.values('user').filter` to `objects.all().filter`, the `value` property of the `<option>` tag will become the `id` of the row. You can then use the incoming `id` from `request.POST` or `request.GET` to store it in your database as any other field you like by running a query. However, in most cases, you probably want to store it as `id` in the database.

Comment: Alright, so after some playing around I can only get the label to change.  I've been searching around for a value override but can't find anything.  Any idea's on how I can do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I had not read the code you passed to the queryset argument carefully.

Comment: hmm, could have sworn i tried that last night.. working now though.  Thank you for the help.