# How to change ForeignKey display text in the Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, foreign-keys, django-admin

How can I change the display text in a `<select>` field while selecting a field which is a `ForeignKey`?

I need to display not only the name of `ForeignKey`, but also the name of its parent.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you want it to take effect only in admin, and not globally, then you could create a custom `ModelChoiceField` subclass, use that in a custom `ModelForm` and then set the relevant admin class to use your customized form.
Using an example which has a ForeignKey to the `Person` model used by @Enrique:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
      person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
      ....

class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      form = MyInvoiceAdminForm


class MyInvoiceAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    person = CustomModelChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.all()) 
    class Meta:
          model = Invoice
      
class CustomModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return "%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
```

Answer (score 62):

Another way of doing so (useful when you change your queryset):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.all()
        self.fields['user'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "%s %s" % (obj.last_name, obj.first_name)
```

`'user'` is the name of field you want to override. This solution gives you one advantage: you can override queryset as well (e.g. you want `User.objects.filter(username__startswith='a')`)

Disclaimer: solution found on http://markmail.org/message/t6lp7iqnpzvlt6qp and tested.

Comment: Old but gold! Thank you!!

Comment: This really helps in non-admin forms and to keep it simple by avoiding a custom class.

Comment: Works like a charm !

Comment: Don't know why it doesn't work for me @Django 2.1.9, but the selected answer works.

Answer (score 18):

Newer versions of django support this, which can be translated with gettext:

```
models.ForeignKey(ForeignStufg, verbose_name='your text')
```

Comment: Documented at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names.

Comment: this actually solves a different problem to the one being asked.

Comment: thats the right way ^^

Answer (score 18):

You can also accomplish this straight from your `admin.ModelAdmin` instance using `label_from_instance`. For example:

```
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['person', 'id']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(InvoiceAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['person'].label_from_instance = lambda inst: "{} {}".format(inst.id, inst.first_name)
        return form


admin.site.register(Invoice, InvoiceAdmin)
```

Comment: This works great. Only issue is that it still presents "field_name(id)" value after adding a value with the admin "+" option. Once the page is reloaded it displays correct. Any idea how to get it to display correct without having to reload?

Answer (score 12):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#unicode

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

you have to define what you want to display in the **unicode** method of your model (where is the ForeignKey).

Regards,

Comment: I know that, but I want to change that in ONLY 1 place on admin elsewhere it shouldn't be changed do that method is not good for me.

Comment: @robos85: Check my answer for what you are looking for. You should also probably update your question.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the other answers, here's a small example for those dealing with a `ManyToManyField`.

We can override `label_from_instance` directly in [formfield_for_manytomany()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany):

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'person':
            # For example, we can add the instance id to the original string
            formfield.label_from_instance = lambda obj: f'{obj} ({obj.id})'
        return formfield
```

This would also work for `formfield_for_foreignkey()` or [formfield_for_dbfield()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L132).

From the [ModelChoiceField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield):

> The `__str__()` method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices. To provide customized representations, subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance`. This method will receive a model object and should return a string suitable for representing it.

Answer (score 2):

By overriding [**formfield_for_foreignkey()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey), you can display **the combination of foreign key and its parent** to **Django Admin** without creating **a custom "forms.ModelChoiceField"** and **a custom "forms.ModelForm"** as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == "my_field":
            formfield.label_from_instance = lambda obj: f'{obj} ({obj.my_parent})'
        return formfield
```

In addition, this code below is with **a custom "forms.ModelForm"**:

```py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                                 
        self.fields['my_field'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: f'{obj} ({obj.my_parent})'

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

And, this code below is with **a custom "forms.ModelChoiceField"** and **a custom "forms.ModelForm"**:

```py
class CustomModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f'{obj} ({obj.my_parent})'

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_field = CustomModelChoiceField(queryset=MyField.objects.all())

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the first answer:

```
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class CustomModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
         def label_from_instance(self, obj):
             return "%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'person':
            return self.CustomModelChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects)

        return super(InvoiceAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found that you can replace the queryset with another queryset, or even remove the queryset and replace it with a choices list. I do this in the `change_view`.

In this example, I let the parent set up the return value, then grab the specific field from it and set `.choices`:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        #get the return value which includes the form
        ret = super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)

        # let's populate some stuff
        form = ret.context_data['adminform'].form

        #replace queryset with choices so that we can specify the "n/a" option
        form.fields['blurb_location'].choices = [(None, 'Subscriber\'s Location')] + list(models.Location.objects.filter(is_corporate=False).values_list('id', 'name').order_by('name'))
        form.fields['blurb_location'].queryset = None

        return ret
```