# Django admin, show 2 or more attributes in a field

Tags: python, django, attributes, admin

I got a model where a "student" is able to enrol to a "course". The issue is that courses may have the same name(but different attendance, 'full time' or 'part time'). So as you can see in the image attached, I would like to know which course a student is enrolled to. Either inside the select box or next to it. I tried to use a list display but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Edit: the field that the type of attendance is stored is called 'attendance' and it's part of the class 'Course'.

admin.py

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.StackedInline):

    model = Student
    verbose_name_plural = 'students'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (StudentAdmin, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `Course` model you can define the `__unicode__(self):` method to interpolate two attributes together. So, in your case you could combine the name of the course and the attendance.

That would look something like this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attendance = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.attendance)
```

Then the string representation of that course will be the name of the course followed by the attendance in parenthesis.

An example of this can be found [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode).

Comment: Perfect! That was really fast! So with this `__unicode__(self)` every time that a **course** will be return it will return also it's type of attendance? Correct?

Comment: Yes. You could create a custom method within the `Course` model to return the name plus attendance if that's a negative as that's the primary advantage to assigning that value to the `__unicode__()` method.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! So in my admin.py how will I ask for `course_and_attendance`?

Comment: I think this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836740/django-admin-change-foreignkey-display-text

Comment: I'll check it!! Once again, thank you for your help!