# How to modify Django admin ManyToManyField text?

Tags: python, django, admin, manytomanyfield

I have "Articles" and "Modules" apps. Inside "Modules" app there is model which have to display articles and they're linked by ManyToManyField in "Modules".

My question is how to modify text value in select field in Django admin? As default it displays names of articles, but i want also some information from Article model here. 
Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Python version, you'll either want to override the models' `__str__` fields (Python 3), or the models' `__unicode__` fields (Python 2) to change how their appear in the admin.

[Reference in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#other-model-instance-methods)

Comment: I would like to avoid altering __str__, because i use it in other places. Maybe I should force the field renderer (?) to use other function, not __str__. But how?

Comment: @user2395401 why do you want to avoid _\_str_\_ ?

Comment: Because I'm already using it to display article title in other places. Here, I want to add something more to title, but only here.

Comment: @moonchild who said you cannot use _\_str_\_ in two places? what do you mean with "other places"

Comment: I mean now my `__str__` returns `self.title` and I use it in several places in frontend to display article title. I could change it to return let's say `self.category + ' | ' + self.title` and that will solve my problem in admin site, but I would have to modify some frontend, so I would like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: @moonchild why and what would you have to modify in frontend because of this? this is just object description, in frontend you can retrieve any data from object you want. what is the big deal?

Answer (score 0):

The Django Admin select menus use the unicode value of the model instance to populate things like menus. Whatever your `__unicode__` method returns should be what is in the select menu.

Answer (score 0):

your question is vague, but i just assume, you have `Article` Model which has manytomany field with e.g. `Something` Model

```
class Something(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  #...
  def __unicode__(self):
    return u"{} whatever text you want".format(self.name)

class Article(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  something = models.ManyToMany(Something)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return u"{}".format(self.title)
```

in admin, you will see `<object_name> whatever text you want` for each object in multiple-select-box, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do this for an admin field, you can use `formfield_for_manytomany`.  In skeleton form it could look like this:

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
    field = super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
    if db_field.name in ['the_field_you_want']:

        # This line answers the question.
        field.label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{}".format(obj.what_you_want_to_see)

        # The lines below included so folks know you can
        # also modify queryset and widget in this method
        field.widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple() # checkboxes
        field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(some_field = something)

    return field #important
```

This came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7805824/1302095) which achieves the same goal but uses a `Form` class instead of `formfield_for_manytomany`.