# django admin foreign key display behavior

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

Now if I go to django Bar's admin, I get dropdown field with Foo's names. I know that name comes from `__unicode__` function in `Foo` class. How can I change that name displayed in admin? I don't want to modify my `__unicode__` function. I would prefer something like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ....
    def unicode_for_admin_display(self):
        return 'some words ' + self.name
```

Comment: Looks there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836740/django-admin-change-foreignkey-display-text

Comment: Yes this is it, thanks.