# Can I create a custom django modelchoicefield with a default queryset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I have an order model with a followed_by field:

```
class order(models.Model):
   followed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "Managers"})
```

I have several such models and forms for those models. By default the form displays a modelchoicefield listing users that are mangers. This is fine. But the display isn't nice: it gives the username, and I want first+last name. This would work nicely: [Change Django ModelChoiceField to show users' full names rather than usernames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167824/change-django-modelchoicefield-to-show-users-full-names-rather-than-usernames)

except that now in everyform I must declare the queryset to limit users to managers. Can I use the above method so that the custom modelchoicefield defaults to my filtered queryset. so then from a form I can just say:

```
followed_by = ManagerUserModelChoiceField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you define the queryset on your `ModelChoiceField` child class?

```
class UserModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    # Query that returns set of valid choices
    queryset = User.objects.filter(group__name='Managers')
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_full_name()
```

Comment: that was actually the first thing I tried but in my form when I declare the following: followed_by = UserModelChoiceField(), I get TypeError:
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given). (See my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the queryset as an argument to the `ManagerUserModelChoiceField` class.

```
followed_by = ModelChoiceField(queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name="Managers")
```

Comment: Whoops - just re-read your question. You already said you didn't want to do this :(

Answer (score 0):

After my comment to @Enrico this thought occurred to me: I overwrote the "init" class on my custom field like so:

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserModelChoiceField, self).__init__(queryset=User.objects.filter(groups__name="Managers"), *args, **kwargs)
```

I've seen stuff like this done in python before but I'm new to python so I'm not sure if this is a bad thing to do or if I should make this better somehow? I'd appreciate some feedback. That being said, it seems to be working correctly.