# Can't save ManyToMany using MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to use custom CHOICE in MultipleChoiceField. I can save everything but not Employees.

## models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.employee_id


class Task(models.Model):
    employee = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, blank=True, null=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.task
```

## forms.py

```
class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    CHOICES = (
        ('123', 'Adam'),
        ('321', 'John'),
        ('666', 'Lucy'),
    )

    employee = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=True)


    def __init__(self, custom_choices=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if custom_choices:
            self.fields['employee'].choices = custom_choices

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

So basically I added `custom_choices`, because I want to show in `MultipleChoiceField` Employee's names `('Adam', 'John' ,'Lucy')` and save their

`employee_id` ('123','321', 666').

## views.py

```
class TaskCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Task
    form_class = TaskCreateForm
    template_name = "task/create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        return redirect('/task_page/')
```

I can see form on my page and I can choose employees, but employee_id is not saving. Only other fields `task` and `comment` are being saved.

## Update for clarification:

There are no names in my models. I just want to show **custom** names for `employee_id`.
That's why I need ('123','Adam') - I want to save '123' but display in my form 'Adam'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the basic solution still stays the same:

```
queryset=Employee.objects.filter(employee_id__in=['some_id', 'other_id'])
```

The key point is that you should use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

If you want to display the names rather than the IDs, there are a couple of ways to do that, e.g. a `get_name` method on the model and a custom ModelMultipleChoiceField, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3167840/1180983

So that would look roughly like this:

```
EMPLOYEE_NAMES = {
    '123': 'Adam',
    '321': 'John',
}

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def get_name(self):
        return EMPLOYEE_NAMES.get(self.employee_id, 'unknown')

class EmployeeMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_name()

class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm)
    employees = EmployeeMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Employee.objects.filter(employee_id__in=['123', '321'])
    )
```

Comment: Hey I have ``AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'EmployeeMultipleChoiceField'``
PyCharm highlighted `EmployeeMultipleChoiceField` in `TaskCreateForm`

Comment: You should change `forms.EmployeeMultipleChoiceField` to `EmployeeMultipleChoiceField`

Comment: Unfortunately I can see only ids. I followed exactly your way

Comment: I did a quick test. This method works for me. Did you maybe use my suggested plural name (``employees``) on the form, but forgot to change your field name on the model (``employee``) accordingly?

Comment: Here is a hg repo with a small demo: https://bitbucket.org/rfleschenberg/so-31047499/

Please note: This is not clean code, it is only meant as a very quick & dirty demo to help you track down your problem. Do not follow my example when it comes to things such as ``import *``.

Comment: Unfortunately, my problem is more complex. And your solution doesn't fit my problem. However If your solution works for you, then I'll accept it.

Here is my real problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053098/display-full-names-in-form-choicefield-but-saving-ids

Answer (score 0):

Your ModelForm does not know what to do with the employee field on `save()`, because you do not tell it anywhere, and that field is not connected to any model. Use a [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) instead.

If you need to restrict the choices the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` allows, use the `queryset` argument:

```
employees = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Employee.objects.filter(name__in=['Alice', 'Bob'])
)
```

Also, think about where to use plural and where to use singular names, so you do not confuse yourself (`employees` instead of `employee` above).

Comment: No, no you guys don't understand. I need only display names and save `employee_id`. In my models there are no names. I just want to display in choicefield names, but saving only ids.

Comment: Employee model only contains `employee_id`. I dont have any names. I just want to display custom names for `employee_id`. I updated my post