# Display full names in Form ChoiceField but saving ID's

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have model Person - from another database
I copied all `person_id` to `custom_id`.

## models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    custom_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    @property
    def person(self):
        return Person.objects.get(person_id='%s' % self.custom_id)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.custom_id

class Task(models.Model):
    employee = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, blank=True, null=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.task
```

I add my method `person()` to Employee which allow me to access other objects model in another database:

So basically when I type this in shell:

```
Employee.objects.get(custom_id='123').person.full_name

u'Adam Dylan'
```

I have a `ModelForm` which use `ModelMultipleChoiceField`

## forms.py

```
class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    employee = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

But `Employee.objects.all()` returns bunch of custom_id's.
What I want is to show in form "`Employee(..).person.full_name`" but saving only `custom_id's`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you think the answer I gave to your other question does not work here. Did you try the following? If it does not work, how exactly does it fail?

```
class EmployeeMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.person.full_name

class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    employee = EmployeeMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

Comment: I had exactly code. But I got this error 
`MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Person -- it returned 2!`

Comment: That means there is more than one ``Person`` that matches the ``custom_id`` of the ``Employee``. You should either clean up your data so that there is only one ``Person`` per ``Employee``, or decide which one to use (e.g. the first), and use ``filter()`` instead of ``get()``:
``return Person.objects.filter(person_id=self.custom_id).first()``