# Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices. (When I try to save dropdown list selected data in database)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I already saw all question on Stackoverflow. But Still Not possible for me to solve this error. I want a dropdown list data to appear on my website. And that data I am getting from another model. So till here I am going good. Now When I try to save this data in database this error appear.

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

My Model is like this

```
 apn = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
```

My form.py file is like this

```
class labelModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Labels_tool
      apn = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Field.objects.values_list('sql_name', flat=True), empty_label="(Choose field)")
```

And view.py file is :

```
 def ImportLabelView(self):
        self.form = labelModelForm(self.request.POST)
        # self.form = self.layer.form(self.request.POST)
        if self.save_form_if_appropriate('label'):
            return self.redirect('mapport.maps.layers.importlabel', self.map.id, self.layer.id)
        return self.render('mapport/maps/layers/Labels_detail.html')
```

Dropdown appearing on page is good . Just issue is when I try to save it in database.

[image: [1]]

Comment: Could you show the entire view, not just a part of it?

Comment: @FazilZaid its full view of template  'Labels_detail.html' . And I am only using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a values list. You should be using a normal queryset and then using `to_field_name` as shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name.

```
apn = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Field.objects.all(), empty_label="(Choose field)", to_field_name="sql_name")
```

Then when you go to save the things just extract the relevant information to save in `apn`, though really `apn` should just be a foreign key onto `Field`.

I would also consider looking at this question to see if it helps you: [Change Django ModelChoiceField to show users' full names rather than usernames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167824/change-django-modelchoicefield-to-show-users-full-names-rather-than-usernames)

I suspect that you are doing something in your database that you shouldn't really be doing.

Comment: I didnt get that. Can you modify a little bit my code please ? to_field_name is my database field ?

Comment: @ephemeral I've added a bit more

Comment: I changed in form but then I get a empty text box instead of dropdown.

Comment: @ephemeral is `sql_name` a model field in `Field`?

Comment: Yes . I am getting dropdown data from Field.sqlname .

Comment: you dont have any suggestion ?

Comment: you were talking right. But my data sequence issue didn't let me work properly. So accepting as you were saying right.