# How to create filter form page with Django filters with object count per category shown in the option labels

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filters

I am new to Django and trying to create a page that shows a list of products with couple of filters. The page works fine using standard method and shows filter and update the page as selected.
What I want to do is to add a count of products available based on the seelcted filters in; in this case just for category.

models.py

```
class Category(index.Indexed, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024, verbose_name="Product title")
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

filters.py

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    category = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Category.objects.annotate(num_product=Count("product"))
    ) 
    last_modified = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(label="Date_Range")

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["category", "last_modified"]
```

views.py

```
def product_explorer_view(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    product_filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=products)
    products = product_filter.qs

    context = {
        "products": products,
        "product_filter": product_filter,
      
    } 
    return render(request, "/products_index.html", context)
```

products_index.html

```
  <form class="mb-1">
        <div class="row g-2">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
            Category:
            <div class="form-floating">
              <!-- <label for="searchTerm" class="form-label">Category</label> -->
              {{ product_filter.form.category }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
            Date:
            <div class="form-floating">
              <!-- <label for="searchTerm" class="form-label">Category</label> -->
              {{ chart_filter.form.last_modified }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-4 pt-1">
            </br>

            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" type="submit">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        Number of available products: {{ products|length }}
      </form>
```

Right now this `Category` option field in the form is filled as below.
Output on page

```
<th><label for="id_category">Category:</label></th>

<td><select name="category" id="id_category">

<option value="">---------</option>
<option value="11" selected>Category1</option>
<option value="12">Category2</option>
<option value="13">Category3</option>
<option value="14">Category4</option>
<option value="16">Category5</option>
<option value="17">Category6</option>
</select></td>
```

What I want is to get

```
<th><label for="id_category">Category:</label></th>
<td>

<select name="category" id="id_category">

<option value="">---------</option>
<option value="11" selected>Category1 (3)</option>
<option value="12">Category2 (5)</option>
<option value="13">Category3 (7)</option>
<option value="14">Category4 (18)</option>
<option value="16">Category5 (20)</option>
<option value="17">Category6 (0)</option>
</select></td>
```

The added annotation in the `filters.py` add that extra variable in the queryset, but it does not help include that in the `<option> labels`.

Is there some configuration/parameter to change that labels?
Or in which other way can I make that other than manually building the select options and then linking it back to product filters?

I assume there must be some Django way of doing it, as it is/should be quite a standard requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attempt #2 :)**

By overriding the form `@property` you can override the *labels* of the select

```py
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    category = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Category.objects.annotate(num_product=Count("product"))
    )
    last_modified = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(label="Date_Range")

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["category", "last_modified"]

    @property
    def form(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_form"):
            Form = self.get_form_class()
            if self.is_bound:
                self._form = Form(self.data, prefix=self.form_prefix)
            else:
                self._form = Form(prefix=self.form_prefix)
            # This line
            self._form.fields['category'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: f'{obj.name} ({obj.num_product})'
        # <- we DO NOT place it here, else it runs 3 times,
        #  we want only during the init!
        return self._form
```

#### Thought process of finding this out

1. Pull django-filter from Github
2. Find `FilterSet` Object, CTRL-SHIFT-F, it's inside `django_filters/filterset.py`
3. Look Look for any form init or field overrides

   - found `def form(self)`
4. Paste entire block into `ProductFilter`, Overriding default.
5. Start `print()`-ing stuff out

   - `vars()` is handy

Structure (trial and error):

```py
print(self._form.fields)
# {
#     'category': <django_filters.fields.ModelChoiceField object at 0x7fd960c26890>,
#     'last_modified': <django_filters.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x7fd960c269b0>
# }
```

6. Google `django override modelchoicefield display`

   - [Change Django ModelChoiceField to show users' full names rather than usernames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167824/change-django-modelchoicefield-to-show-users-full-names-rather-than-usernames)
7. Choose the lambda answer because i'm **not** creating a custom ModelChoiceField

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, I am NOT generating that select>option list manually. That part is done by the template with the line `<div class="form-floating">
              <!-- <label for="searchTerm" class="form-label">Category</label> -->
              {{ product_filter.form.category }}
            </div>` in `products_index.html`. I was trying to find a way to keep the same functionality but changing this FilterSet/Filter or any other library or paramters, where I can say that when the `.html` renders it show `category name ( count of products)`

Comment: No, it was very clear on my second read. I missed that entire block for some reason and that you were using some random package. Updated my answer and explained how I found it, hopefully it helps in the future

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Sorry, i took some time to reply back as all these onvoluted class loops often with same names from different libraries was a bit too much :). But I am happy now that it is working. I also added further code to limit the form fiields based on the queryset as it was in your original answer. Just then I had to implement to show selected filters and clear filters code as well to make it clear why certain cateogries do not show. Seems like standard, but needed some work :).